# strtok to split only spaces preceded by a /?

Tags: c, string, unix, posix

I am trying to write my own shell, and so far I have been getting my command lines arguments by using `strtok` and splitting on white spaces. This works great in most cases except they are are situations when some commands use file paths with spaces such as :

```
ls -la /users/bayesianStudent/desktop/test\ sample/documents/unread\ stuff
```

In these cases, the strtok function splits even in between the path. Is there a way to avoid this and get only 3 tokens for instance in the above command say by splitting only when space is not preceded by a / ? Following is my code so far:

```
char ** getCommands(char * input )
{
    char ** result = NULL;
    int spaces = 0;
    char * token = strtok(input, " ");

   /* split string and append tokens to 'res' */

    while (token) {
      result = realloc (result, sizeof (char*) * ++spaces);

      if (result == NULL)
          exit (-1); /* memory allocation failed */

      result[spaces-1] = token;

      token = strtok (NULL, " ");
  }

/* realloc one extra element for the last NULL */

  result = realloc (result, sizeof (char*) * (spaces+1));
  result[spaces] = 0;

  return result;
}
```

Comment: `strtok` is really not that sophisticated. You need to implement your own parser.

Comment: No, `strtok()` cannot do this.  It also would not help you avoid splitting at spaces within quoted strings, in case you envision ever wanting that.

Comment: You need a finite-state-machine based parser, or `yacc`/`bison`. The "\" can be used to escape other special characters too. As others have said, it can't be done with `strtok` and thus the question "how to do it with strtok" is impossible to answer.